# React HOC preventing prop transfer from index.js to app.js

Tags: reactjs

problem -> i have created a higher order component(hoc) (that is withClass). than i am not getting the data through props from index.js to app.js .like i am not getting value of title prop in app.js.

where am i wrong .

i am getting this issue only after hoc .before of this it was working fine .

```js
//App.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import classes from './App.module.css';

import Persons from '../components/Persons/Persons';
import Cockpit from '../components/Cockpit/Cockpit';
import Aux from '../hoc/Auxilary';
import withClass from '../hoc/withClass';

class App extends Component{
  
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    console.log("[App.js] constructor");
  }


  state = {    
    persons:[
      { id:'asfgfg34',name:'amrish',age:24},
      { id:'asdf343',name:'amrish1',age:24},
      { id:'232cvf',name:'amrish2',age:23}
    ],
    showPersons:false ,
    showCockpit:true
   };
   
   static getDerivedStateFromProps(props,state)
   {
     console.log('[App.js] getDerivedStateFromProps',props);
     return state;
   }

   componentDidMount(){
     console.log('[App.js] componentDidMount'); 
     console.log(this.props.title); // here i am getting undefined 
   }
   componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("componentDidUpdate");
  
  }
  
  
  deletePerson = (index)=>{

    let person = [...this.state.persons];
    person.splice(index,1);

    this.setState({persons:person});
   };

  nameChangedHandler = (event,id) =>{

    const personIndex = this.state.persons.findIndex(person=>{
      return person.id === id;
    });

   // console.log("before update="+this.props.persons);

    const personUpdated = {
      ...this.state.persons[personIndex]
    };
   // console.log(personUpdated)  ;
    personUpdated.name = event.target.value;

    console.log(personUpdated.name);


    const persons = [...this.state.persons];

    persons[personIndex] = personUpdated;


    this.setState({
      persons:persons
    });

    //console.log("after update="+this.props.persons);

  };
  
  togglePersonsHandler = ()=>{
    const doesShow = this.state.showPersons;
    this.setState({showPersons:!doesShow});
   };


    render()
    { 
      console.log('[App.js] render');
      let person = null ;
      let cockpit = null;
      if(this.state.showPersons)
      { 
        person = (
              <Persons  persons={this.state.persons} 
              deletePerson = {this.deletePerson}
              nameChangedHandler = {this.nameChangedHandler}
                />
        );
        
      }

      if(this.state.showCockpit)
      {
        cockpit = (
          <Cockpit  togglePersonsHandler={this.togglePersonsHandler}  showPersons ={this.state.showPersons}
          personsLength = {this.state.persons.length}
          title={this.props.title}
          />
        );
      }
      
      return (
        
        <Aux>
          <button  onClick={()=>{ let isshown = !this.state.showCockpit;return this.setState( {showCockpit : isshown} )} }>Remove cockpit</button>
          {
            cockpit
          }
          {
            person
          }        
        </Aux>
        
      );
      
    }
    
    }
    
export default withClass(App,classes.App);  // i have made this higher order component after that i 
//am facing this issue.




//index.js


import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './containers/App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

// i am passing title from this file as "Person Manager"

ReactDOM.render(
    <App title="Person Manager"/>
 ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

---

```
//withClass.js

import React from 'react';

const withClass = (WrappedComponent,classes)=>{
    
    return props=> (
        <div  className={classes}>
            <WrappedComponent></WrappedComponent>
        </div>
    );
};

export default withClass;
```

Comment: You need to pass the props to the wrapped component in the HOC. Something like
```<WrappedComponents {...props} />```

Comment: thank you so much ,it works fine.  but can you please explain .why i have to pass props there .

Answer (score 1):

HOC composes the the original component by wrapping it in another component. So you end up with nested component. When you pass props to the HOC component, you have to pass them down to the original component in order to be able to use them there. There is more information about this in [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

So your HOC should look like this:

```
import React from 'react';

const withClass = (WrappedComponent,classes)=>{
    
    return props=> (
        <div  className={classes}>
            <WrappedComponent {...props} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default withClass;
```